# Win32 API FindFirstChangeNotification prevents hardware safe removal

Tags: winapi, filesystemwatcher

We use `FindFirstChangeNotification` with `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME` and `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` to monitor for changes in files and directories.

But, this prevents the user from safely remove hardware. When it tries to, Windows shows this error message:

[image]

So the user has to shutdown our app to be able to remove external drive safely.

Is there any workaround? Why does it prevent safe removal? We are not using external drive, just monitoring it for changes.

Code we use:

```
auto h = FindFirstChangeNotification(
                path,
                TRUE,
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);

WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE);
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a98c405-e96d-4d23-8e6d-3d1e51075164/mfc-findfirstchangenotification-prevent-eject-usb?forum=vcgeneral?

Comment: *Why does it prevent safe removal* for get notifications need have open directory file. so `FindFirstChangeNotification` internally open handle for `path`. from another side for safe removal need close all handles on device and it mount file system.

Comment: Use RegisterDeviceNotification to get notified when the system wants to remove a device. This lets you close your outstanding handles.

Comment: OK, thanks. Feel free to post it as an answer if you want to, I will mark it then.